# Git: How to get a listing of all untracked files, ignoring untracked submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

In a script, I want to check whether a Git repository is clean or not. In case it's not clean, changes should be stashed away. For the check, I'm using:

```
git diff-index HEAD --
```

to figure out modifications of tracked files and:

```
git ls-files --others
```

to figure out whether untracked files are present. Unfortunately, `git ls-files --others` will also report untracked submodules which can't be stashed away.

Is there some option or a different Git command which returns the same result as `git ls-files --other` **except of untracked submodules**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` cannot see whether an untracked directory is **supposed** to become a submodule or not. It is just an untracked directory.

You might check for a `.git` subdirectory to check if that untracked directory is in fact a `git` repository; something like:

```
for untracked in $(git ls-files --others)
do
    if [ ! -e $untracked/.git ]
    then
        echo $untracked
    fi
done
```

which would print the untracked files/directories that are not a git repository.

## Git alias

you can set it up as a git alias like this:

```
git config --global alias.untracked-not-repo '!'"bash -c 'for untracked in \$(git ls-files --others); do if [ ! -e \$untracked/.git ]; then echo \$untracked; fi; done'"
```

now you can use it like

```
git untracked-not-repo
```

Comment: In my case the untracked directory already contains `.git`, so it's a (not yet registered) submodule. `git stash` recognizes this submodule and shows a warning that it can't be stashed.

Comment: @mstrap yes I got that. My command will list untracked files but ignores git repositories, just like your question asks...?

Comment: Sorry, Chris, I somehow misunderstood. The alias you gave fails for me on Windows (`expansion of alias 'untracked-not-repo' failed; '!bash' is not a git command`), but I should be able to fix this myself. Overall, I was hoping for some officially supported Git command/option/flag, but I guess there is none.

Comment: @mstrap I didn't know you were working on windows, then `bash` isn't going to work indeed... probably you can rewrite the logic in any other language that you have available on windows, you get the idea.
I'm quite sure there is not official git flag for this.